# Centering text in a fluid layout

Tags: html, css, centering

I have a website with a fluid/dynamic layout in which I need to center specific text elements between images. Everything is all fine and dandy and I have done so by changing the margins of the text elements, however if I were to change the text inside my p tags, the images would no longer be aligned they way they are or the text would no longer appear exactly centered next to the adjacent images.

JSFiddle that resembles my "problem": http://jsfiddle.net/3s4bhwg4/4/

Ideal image if my JSFiddle does not look correct:

[image]

Is there a more maintainable way to achieve the same results of centering the text or is using margins to this extent acceptable/considered good practice?

I'm very rusty with web design, so I'll take any criticism happily.

Note: Resizing the JSFiddle width seems to break the layout. However resizing it on my local webpage keeps it constant....

CSS:

```
#wrapper{

    MARGIN-LEFT: auto; 
    MARGIN-RIGHT: auto; 
    WIDTH: 100%; 

}

.row{
    width: 100%;
}

/*Please execuse my use of left/right in naming my ids. */
#contentleft{
    float: left;
    width: 60%;
}

#contentleft h1{
    margin: 30% 5% 0 40%;
}

#contentleft p{
   margin: 0 5% 0 40%; 
}

#contentright{
    float: right;
    width: 40%;
}

#contentright p{
    margin: 17% 30% 43% 10%;
}

img{
    width: 100%;   
}
```

HTML:

```
<div id="wrapper">
    <div class="row">Header</div>
    <div id="contentleft">
        <IMG src="http://img2.wikia.nocookie.net/__cb20081223173835/uncyclopedia/images/7/7e/Mountain.jpg"></IMG>

        <H1>Random.</H1>

        <P> Both texts must be centered next to their adjacent images as well. </P>                                     
    </div>

    <div id="contentright">

            <P>The margins of this text pushes the image down so it aligns with the corner of the other image.
            </P>
            <IMG src="https://c1.staticflickr.com/5/4081/4811391918_7d607682b6_z.jpg"></IMG>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Is there a reason why you chose vertical layout? Why not swap the paragraphs of text so they are in the same div as the image they are ascociated with and then set their top and bottom margin to auto?

Comment: based on the image, it looks like a table would work too. vertical aligning text is easiest to do in table cells, just use `vertical-align="middle"` on the td. first row has image then text in their own cells, then the second row has text then image.

Comment: The table is probably best, but I should add that, using divs the image and the p would also need to be formatted as inline-block.

Comment: I spent a while trying to get this to work and the best I could do is dynamic with text aligned at the top. Also I would point out that if your image expands to fill the same size as the text occupies this could result in it being stretched. I'm not done trying yet though.

Comment: Cool Blue, could you elaborate please on how you would align the text to the right when the image is on the right side? If I add a width to make the text wrap and try to align the text, a large space still remains between image and text. And I appreciate your efforts Blue

Comment: *"Resizing the JSFiddle width seems to break the layout. However resizing it on my local webpage keeps it constant...."* - If the demo isn't working properly, then how can we check and fix the issue at hand??!

Comment: Yep, my idea doesn't work: I thought I could flow an `inline-block` div next to the image but it aligns the bottom of the text in the div with the bottom of the container... Table is a good idea, my attempt is in my answer.

Comment: Also using inline-blocks (although the white space between blocks makes it not perfect):  [JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/CoolBlue/ufbpy2Lc/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the closest I could get using a table as suggested by @JStephen: [JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/CoolBlue/zopbxk7p/7/)

The only way I could make it work was to keep one image un-scaled.
And I couldn't get them to meet exactly in the corners.

EDIT:
Working correctly now...
[image][image]
I managed to hack it by inserting the lower image in the cell above it in the first row, setting its height to 1px and opacity to 0 and floating it.  This works because the table layout is fixed so the first row is used to format the table.  (By floating the hidden image, the centering of the text is unaffected.) I then set the width of the visible copy of the second image to 100%.

Added `padding: 0;` in td as well as `border-collapse: collapse;` in Table to make the corners touch exactly like your pic.  (It seems the default padding is not zero)

It works as long as the height of the text is less than that of the (visible) images

HTML

```
<body>
    <div class="row">Header</div>
    <table id="wrapper">
        <tr id="cont-top">
            <td>
                <img src="http://img2.wikia.nocookie.net/__cb20081223173835/uncyclopedia/images/7/7e/Mountain.jpg" />
            </td>
            <td>
                <img src="https://c1.staticflickr.com/5/4081/4811391918_7d607682b6_z.jpg" />
                <p>The margins of this text pushes the image down so it aligns with the corner of the other image.</p>
            </td>
        </tr>

        <tr id="cont-bottom">
            <td>
                <h1>Random.</h1>
                <p> Both texts must be centered next to their adjacent images as well. </p>
            </td>
            <td>
                <img src="https://c1.staticflickr.com/5/4081/4811391918_7d607682b6_z.jpg" />
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>

</body>
```

CSS

```
#wrapper {
    MARGIN-LEFT: auto;
    MARGIN-RIGHT: auto;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    table-layout: fixed;
    border-collapse: collapse;
    z-index: 0;
}
td, tr{
    padding: 0;
    position: relative;
}
td{
    /*outline: 1px dotted red;*/
}
.row {
    width: 100%;
        padding: 0.5em;
        height: 4%;
}
/*top row********/
#cont-top {
    height: auto;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
    /*image*/
    #cont-top td:first-child {
        width: 60%;
    }
    #cont-top img{
        width: 100%;
        vertical-align: bottom;
        z-index: 20;
    }
    /*text*/
    #cont-top td:last-child{
        padding: 0;
    }
    #cont-top td:last-child p {
        margin: 0 10px;
        vertical-align: central;
    }
    /*formatting hack*/
    #cont-top td:last-child img{
        width: 100%;
        height: 1px;
        line-height: 1px;
        float: left;
        /*opacity: 0;*/
    }
/*bottom row********/
#cont-bottom {
    height: auto;
    position: relative;
}
    /*image*/
    #cont-bottom td:last-child {
        vertical-align: top;
    }

    #cont-bottom img{
        vertical-align: top;
        width: 100%;
        left: 0;
        z-index: 20;
    }
    /*text*/
    #cont-bottom td:first-child {
        vertical-align: central;
        padding: 0 10px;
    }
```